# Spring/Hibernate: Table is not created - "Error executing DDL ...."

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In my structure, each "Task" has OneToOne relation with one "Problem" and each "Problem" has OneToOne with a "Solution". A "Solution" has a list of "Items".

I cannot find a way to make it work. when hibernates starts I have this exception and the table "Item" is not created.

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table item add constraint FKmkmqr7wiqxa0t51p9k4c9kbkb foreign key (solution_id) references solution (id)" via JDBC Statement
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]

The code is below (omitting getters and setters).
Task

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true,
value = {"id"})
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("task")
    private String taskName;

    private String status;

    private Timestamps timestamps;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Problem> problem;

    public Task(){
    }
}
```

Problem

```
@Entity
public class Problem {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   private Integer capacity;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="weights", 
   joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="problem_id"))
   @Column(name="weights")
   private List<Integer> weights;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="_values", 
   joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="problem_id"))
   @Column(name="_values")
   private List<Integer> values;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JsonIgnore
   private Task task;

   @OneToOne
  private Solution solution;
}
```

Solution:

```
@Entity
public class Solution {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Task task;
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Problem problem;

@OneToMany
private List<Item> items;
}
```

Item:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private Integer values;
private Integer weight;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JsonIgnore
private Solution solution;
```

}

Comment: you did not mentioned the **foreign key** name. Add `@JoinColumn(name = "solution_id")` annotation at `Item` table after `@ManyToOne` annotation.

Comment: It doesn`t work. Same error.

Comment: by *same error* you mean - the error is still for the **item** table?

Comment: The error was the same. I just figured out. It was the variable "values". It generates a syntax error in mysql.

Comment: If you are facing difficulties in generating pojo's, you can use hibernate reverse engineering which will auto generate the pojo's based on the database schema. So that you don't need to worry about schema errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with having a variable/field called "values". "values" is a reserved word in Mysql, so the query generated by Spring JPA is invalid.

One solution is simply to change the variable "values" to "_values" or add the annotation `@Column(name = "_value")` if you need to keep the name in the code the same.